# Is it possible to programatically change the TextValue and icon in Action Bar Sherlock?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

What I want to achieve is change in a dynamic way `TextView` in `ActionBar` to show specific value of some field.

What I want to achieve is to create a badge like solution in ABS with counter of some items.
I know how to replace graphic in ABS, but this is beyond scope of my understanding.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null)
        {
            actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background));
            actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
            actionBar.setTitle(title);
        }
```

Comment: I will test it out, and let you know. it looks promising :-).

Comment: Hi mate, if it did the trick it could be nice if you'll accept the answer.. :)

Comment: I'm testing it right now, and it's still not what I need. What I need to do is to populate ABS with custom view, for which I have prepared layout resource. Any idea if it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
  int titleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");

    TextView yourTextView = (TextView)findViewById(titleId);
    yourTextView.setText("TITLE TEXT");
```